# SAPUI5/OpenUI5 Routing without "#" possible?

Tags: oauth-2.0, sapui5

I have an application with two routes ("" and "page") with a simple target attached to each (not the same). When I now navigate from the root route "" to "page", the URL in the URL bar of the browser changes to `<baseurl>#/page`. Also when simply entering `<baseurl>#/page` in the URL bar of the browser, the proper view is displayed, that was configured via route and target.

Is it possible to configure UI5 - presumably the router - to omit the `#` in the URL, such that navigation changes the URL to `<baseurl>/page` and simply entering `<baseurl>/page` brings me to the corresponding page?

My use case is the following: I want to have an application with OAuth login (implicit grant flow) with a dedicated route/view/controller to handle the callback. The authorization server asks for the callback URL to be configured and forbids the usage of the symbol `#` in the callback URL, which makes sense as the implicit flow will pass the data back either within the fragement of the URL, which would be appended after the `#` of my URL violating the URL anatomy.

Comment: It's not supported by default but should be possible by extending the Router related classes. Afaik, this is what the UI5 team did for the Demo Kit. I'd suggest to create an enhancement request on GitHub

Comment: GitHub request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2993