# How to get rid of the hash symbol (`#`) in the URL in UI5-routing?

Tags: sapui5

Starting the `1.83.x`/`1.84.x` OpenUI5 versions there is a possibility to omit the hash symbol (`#`) from the browser routing URL.

The new URL-format vs. the old-one:

- https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d
- https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d

I've checked the OpenUI5 documentation but could not find how to get rid of this `#` in the URL.

Is it somewhere in `manifest.json`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/63232562/5846045

Comment: The question you've provided a link above is too wordy, I believe that this question is much easier to find and to understand. Besides, that question doesn't have an accepted answer, while this one already has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenUI5 Demo Kit is using a custom Router in order to improve its SEO. See [commit `4614eb0`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/4614eb0caa35fca6258b3bb50b48da5179381679).

Routing without `#` is not officially supported **yet.** There is an enhancement request though: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2993